# Implementing a timeout property on Stream Read

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stream

I'm getting a stream from `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()` where I'm reading data from.
Now I want to implement a `Timeout` property. The easiest way to do it would be `stream.ReadTimeout = timeout` but this throws an `InvalidOperationException -> Timeouts are not supported on this stream`.

Given this, I'm trying to implement the timeout property myself but got stuck on a dispose. This is what I got so far:

```
public class MyStream : Stream {
    private readonly Stream _src;
    public override int ReadTimeout { get; set; }

    public MyStream (Stream src, int timeout) {
       ReadTimeout = timeout;
       _src = src;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
        var timer = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        int read = 0;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            _ => {
                read = _src.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                timer.Set();
            });
        bool completed = timer.WaitOne(ReadTimeout);
        if (completed) {
            return read;
        }
        throw new TimeoutException(string.Format("waited {0} miliseconds", ReadTimeout));
    }
```

The problem with this code is after is throws a `TimeoutException` that is being properly handled somewhere. It throws an Exception on `_src.Read(buffer, offset, count)` saying that the _src stream was disposed.

Is there a way to cancel the ThreadPool method or should I use a better approach and which one?

Thanks

**EDIT**

As asked by @JotaBe, were's the code where I get the stream from HttpWebResponse:

```
_httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

_httpRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
_httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(
    result =>
        {
            try {
                _httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)_httpRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
                stream = _httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            }
            catch (WebException) {
                downloadCompleted.Set();
                Abort();
            }
            finally {
                downloadCompleted.Set();
            }
        },
        null);

    bool completed = downloadCompleted.WaitOne(15 * 1000);
    if (completed) {
        return new MyStream(stream, 10000);
    }
```

Comment: You might just be able to use [`Stream.BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread(v=vs.95).aspx) and use the `AsyncWaitHandle` property of `IAsyncResult` to wait on it rather than hand rolling it.

Comment: If you're not too far down this path and are open to exploring an alternative, I've found that using the Reactive Extensions (Rx) makes this sort of thing trivial. There is also the WP7Contrib project on codeplex. It has an entire network communications aspect that is all based on Rx that you can leverage.

Comment: @vcsjones I want the timeout to prevent infinite waiting times and although async is a good practice, it's not the problem here

Comment: Could you not just put a try/catch around your two lines of code in the workitem?  If you wanted to you could re-throw any exceptions that aren't the 'disposed' exception you're getting when timing out.

Comment: @Nomad101 Yes I could. I'm just looking if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @Daniel There is an overload of [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx) that accepts a timeout.

Comment: @vcsjones, I'm using that =) the problem is that after the timeout, if I'm not able to read from the stream, I throw the exception and call MyStream.Close which will dispose of the _src stream giving an ObjectDisposedException inside the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using Nomad101 suggestion and surround the read with a try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get a timeout if you don't receive and answer form a web server, you're trying to do it in the wrong place.

To get a Response, you usually make a Request:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
```

This is the operation which can timeout. You have to call it in a differente way, using the  Begin/End asynchronous pattern.

There is a full example of this in
[MSDN doc for HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)

This example uses a callback function. However, there are many different ways to use Begin/End. For example, you can use a WaitHandle available in IAsyncResult like this:

```
IAsyncResult ar = req.BeginGetResponse(yourCallback, null);
bool completed = ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(15000 /*your timeout in miliseconds*/);
```

This will wait 15 seconds. If the response arrives before this, completed will be true. If not, completed will be false. You can then use the `HttpWebRequest.Abort()` method to abort the request.

The Begin/End pattern takes charge of managing the neccesary threads.

Comment: I receive an answer from the webservice, but this specific request is for a Stream so instead of using the .GetResponse() or .BeginGetResponse() methods I'm using the .GetResponseStream() method and 100% of the time I'm able to do at least the first stream.Read() with success. Sometimes on the second or one of the following reads is where I get the timeout.

Comment: Also, you can try to use a method instead of an anonymous delegate. Look at this from the doc: "You can place data required by the queued method in the instance fields of the class in which the method is defined, or you can use the QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback, Object) overload that accepts an object containing the necessary data